# Adding a label column to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where I get the stocks data (OHLC) and date as index. However, the ticker name is not shown there. 
So, data looks something like this :

```
                open      high       low     close     volume
date                                                         
2013-10-11   63.7003   64.5963   63.4609   64.4619   66934938
2013-10-14   64.0718   65.0855   64.0090   64.8841   65474542
2013-10-15   65.0757   65.6637   64.8161   65.2294   80018603
2013-10-16   65.5054   65.7330   65.3014   65.5478   62775013
2013-10-17   65.3995   66.0273   65.3602   65.9907   63398335
2013-10-18   66.1856   66.6133   66.1490   66.5649   72635570
```

I have a list of ticker symbols and I am running a for loop to get the same and then using concat/append to finally get the data. However, I want to add ticker symbols here. How can I do it ?

Below is the final output :

```
                open      high       low     close     volume   ticker
date                                                         
2013-10-11   63.7003   64.5963   63.4609   64.4619   66934938   AAPL
2013-10-14   64.0718   65.0855   64.0090   64.8841   65474542   AAPL
2013-10-15   65.0757   65.6637   64.8161   65.2294   80018603   AAPL
2013-10-16   65.5054   65.7330   65.3014   65.5478   62775013   AAPL
2013-10-17   65.3995   66.0273   65.3602   65.9907   63398335   AAPL
.................
.................
.................
.................
2013-10-11  153.0422  154.3197  152.9154  154.2654  104967037   SPY
2013-10-14  153.3140  155.0083  153.1962  154.8815  111901876   SPY
2013-10-15  154.4919  155.0718  153.5496  153.7580  153958055   SPY
2013-10-16  154.6822  155.9869  154.6051  155.9053  161058684   SPY
2013-10-17  155.2711  157.0379  155.2439  156.9473  129004482   SPY
```

PS : I am using iexfinance library to get historical prices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `iexfinance` library. But Let's say you have a magic function `get_data_from_ticker` which, as the name implies, gets data given a ticker input, possibly as a `pd.DataFrame` object.

Given a list `tickers`, your current process may look like:

```
dfs = []
for ticker in tickers:
    data = get_data_from_ticker(ticker)
    dfs.append(data)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This isn't particularly useful if the ticker information is not stored in your dataframe. So you can use [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a series accordingly:

```
dfs = []
for ticker in tickers:
    data = get_data_from_ticker(ticker)
    dfs.append(data.assign(ticker=ticker))
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Finally, you can make this a more efficient by using a list comprehension:

```
dfs = [get_data_from_ticker(ticker).assign(ticker=ticker) for ticker in tickers]

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: You might also consider using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension as the iterable you pass to `pd.concat`. This should reduce the memory footprint of your script by roughly a factor of 2 before you start doing any further processing.

Comment: Thanks @jpp, it works like a charm. I always have issue while I am labeling some value which is not present in a dataframe. I think 'assign' is a good choice for that.